# Tax Free shopping in Sweden departing from Copenhagen with a stopover in Helsinki

Tags: customs-and-immigration, sweden, tax-refunds

I want to use **global blue tax free** shopping in Sweden, but the goods should be presented to the customs officer when leaving the country. How to do this in practice as passport will be checked in Helsinki and the purchases would be checked in at Copenhagen airport and there is no customs at the border at the Oresund bridge.

What would be the correct procedure here?

Comment: So to confirm, your shopping was done in Sweden, you're flying out from Copenhagen and you leave the Schengen area at Helsinki? Will the purchases be in checked baggage?

Comment: There is a customs office at the Öresund bridge, located at Ollebovägen 18, 218 45 Vintrie (directly at the last exit on Swedish side before you reach the road toll station).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This question is a bit confusing by the order the OP shows the itinerary.

I assume the following:

- The OP buys goods in Sweden and obtains a receipt. The customer pays full price
- The OP crosses the Oresund bridge to Denmark, no border control, no customs. The OP is with their receipt
- The OP flies to Helsinki, still no border control
- The OP exits the Schengen area to their final destination in Helsinki, hence passport control

I think [Global Blue themselves](https://cs.globalblue.com/s/article/FAQs-About-Customs-Validation?language=en_US) show the answer (emphasis mine)

> I purchased goods in an EU member state, and I am having a transit / connecting flight to my home country from another EU member state. How do I obtain Customs stamp?

> For goods in your hold baggage get Customs stamp at the airport, where you **initially check in for your flight**.
> For goods in your hand baggage receive Customs stamp at your final **point of departure** from the EU.

So two:

- OP *either* uses hand baggage *or* goods are **not checked through** Helsinki: get the customs stamp at Helsinki
- OP puts the goods in a checked bag at CPH, **through** Helsinki: get customs stamp at Copenhagen

Oresund bridge is irrelevant

Comment: For greater precision, what matters is when the purchaser is leaving the EU with the goods, not the Schengen area, if OP is flying from Helsinki to e.g. Ireland or Romania, even if there is passport control, the customs stamp may need to be obtained somewhere else (the final departure from the European Union).